# How to add a string to every file opened in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, uptime

I have a lot of domains and it's getting hard to manage so I want to add a string to the end of every file opened in Apache so I can request any domain if check if the string is there so I will know the domain is working and with my dns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mod_Layout](http://tangent.org/362/mod_layout.html) should do the trick; it allows you to add a header/footer to all displayed pages of a certain file type, so you could add your string as a HTML comment.

```
<!-- This webpage is provided by XCompany! -->
```

And search for that.  Shouldn't effect any of the websites while giving you what you need.